# Working with NSArray and NSDictionary to store facebook friends to later be used in application

Tags: facebook, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to work with `NSArray`s and `NSDictionary`s to store the users facebook friend information. The data will later be used in a table view.

Ideally I would like the information to be stored alphabetically as well if this is possible.

I have successfully made the connection to Facebook and retrieved the result which is like this:

```
(
        {
        "first_name" = Bob;
        id = 999999999;
        "last_name" = Geldof;
        name = "Bob Geldof";
        username = "bob.geldof";
    },
        {
        "first_name" = Someone;
        id = 111111111;
        "last_name" = Else;
        name = "Someone Else";
        username = "someone.else.2";
    },
```

I think this is an NSArray with a Dictionary for each of the users.

What I am trying to achieve is to save the same format of data. I would like to save the id of the user and the full name (name) object, but not sure what is the correct way to do this? Do I need to create a Dictionary for each of the user and add that information?

```
NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"%@",data);
NSMutableArray *facebookIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:data.count];
     for (NSDictionary *friendData in data) {
         NSDictionary *individualFriendInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[friendData objectForKey:@"id"],[friendData objectForKey:@"name"], nil ] forKeys: [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"id", @"name", nil ]];
        [facebookIds addObject:individualFriendInfo];
     }
```

For example the above, saves the following:

```
[{"id":"999999999","name":"Bob Geldof"},{"id":"111111111","name":"Someone Else"}, ....
```

How do I now access these individual dictionaries in a cell? Also what would I need to add to the above so that the order of the dictionaries is saved into the overall Array in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `NSUserDefaults` for Storing NSMutableArray. ane use it later you can store array in to  `NSUserDefaults` like:-

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:yourArray forKey:@"MyFBInfo"];
```

and you can get this array like:-

```
NSMutableArray *facebookIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

facebookIds=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"MyFBInfo"];
```

after you can yous it in `CellforRowAtIndex:` using dictionary like:-

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = (NSMutableDictionary *) [facebookIds.ArrInfoListAlldata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text=[d valueForKey:@"name"];
```

for sorting alphabetically A to Z array check bellow Example:-

https://github.com/elc/ICB_SectionedTableViewDemo

Comment: How do I then access each element of the dictionary within the array for each row? For example : cell.textLabel.text = [self.fbFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; ?? How do I also alphabetically order the dictionaries saved in the original array?